# Can't attach Boinc project on Redhat 8: authentication error

Tags: rhel, sudo, authentication

I am unable to attach a Boinc project on Redhat 8 though `boinc-client` is running properly.

```
# sudo -u boinc boinccmd --project_attach http://www.worldcommunitygrid.org <token>
Operation failed: authentication error
```

This command works on Ubuntu with the same token.

**Why do I get this error and how to attach the project?**

Answer (score 1):

I encountered exactly the same issue. The trick is very simple, you need to `cd /var/lib/boinc` before issuing the command

Comment: This trick worked for me. Which is weird, this should be considered a bug. I had to run with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
systemctl restart boinc-client
cat /var/lib/boinc/gui_rpc_auth.cfg > /etc/boinc-client/gui_rpc_auth.cfg 
cd /etc/boinc-client
boinccmd --create_account http://www.worldcommunitygrid.org <email> <pass> <username>
boinccmd --lookup_account http://www.worldcommunitygrid.org <email> <pass>
boinccmd --project_attach http://www.worldcommunitygrid.org <token>
```